# Script is supposed to create file and write data in it, file gets created but is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data off yelp.com and write it in a file(which has to be created), but the file only gets created with no data inside it. The Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc='
location = 'San+Francisco,+CA,+United+States'
current_page=0
while current_page<=970:
    url = base_url+location+'&start='+str(current_page)
    #print(url)
    yelp_r = requests.get(url)
    yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_r.text,'html.parser')    
    file_path='restraunt_locations/yelp-{loc}.txt'.format(loc=location)
    with open(file_path,'a') as txtfile:
        items = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc largerScrollablePhotos__373c0__3FEIJ arrange__373c0__UHqhV border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'})
        for item in items:
            name = item.findAll('a',{'class':'lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__29943 link-color--blue-dark__373c0__1mhJo link-size--inherit__373c0__2JXk5'})[0].text
            print ('Name : '+name)
            if item.findAll('address'):
                address = item.findAll('address')[0].text
            else:
                address = 'Could Not find Location'
            print('Location: '+address)
            phone = item.findAll('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__2de_K border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'})
            if not phone:
                Phone = "Could not find Phone Number"
                print('Could not get Phone Number')
            else:
                if phone is not '':
                    Phone = item.findAll('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc display--inline-block__373c0__2de_K border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'})[0].text
                    print('Phone : '+Phone)
                else:
                    Phone = 'Could not find Phone Number'
                    print('Could not get Phone Number')
            #print('\n')
            page_line = 'Name: {title} \t Address : {address} \t Phone : {phone} \n '.format(
                title = name,
                address = address,
                phone = Phone
                )
            txtfile.write(page_line)
    current_page += 10
```

When i tried to just print the data without the whole with open file thing, it worked really well and printed all data out as expected, but when i tried to write it in the file, the file with the expected name is created but there is no data in it, and there is no data printed as well.

Comment: Can you print `page_line` inside your loop?

Comment: I'm betting the following line is returning `None`: `items = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc largerScrollablePhotos__373c0__3FEIJ arrange__373c0__UHqhV border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'})` Which means everything in your loop is not executing including the `txtfile.write(page_line)`

Comment: i tried print(page_line), it does not print anything

Comment: Verify your `items = yelp_soup.findAll(...` is returning what you are expecting it to

Comment: It returns nothing, it just prints nothing and the program ends just creating the empty file

Comment: then you need to debug what is wrong in your code. Voting to close this question.

Comment: " I'm betting the following line is returning None: items = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'lemon--div__373c0__1mboc largerScrollablePhotos__373c0__3FEIJ arrange__373c0__UHqhV border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT'}) Which means everything in your loop is not executing including the txtfile.write(page_line) "

if this is the case, what should i do to make sure and also fix it?

Comment: That line is looking for a `div` in `yelp_soup` that has `class` equal to that long string. By returning `None` it is saying that a `div` with that `class` is not in your html. You either made a mistake with the class, or there are just none to find.

Comment: " That line is looking for a div in yelp_soup that has class equal to that long string. By returning None it is saying that a div with that class is not in your html. You either made a mistake with the class, or there are just none to find. " - But that same very line was working before i added the open file stuff and was simply printing the data, it worked without any errors, and i just copy pasted it when i created the with open block to write the data, inside it, it prints nothing, outside, it does...

Comment: Define `items` outside your `with open()` block and print it, then inside the `with open()` block and print it to prove to yourself that that is not your problem.

Comment: " Define items outside your with open() and print it, then inside the with open() block and print it to prove to yourself that that is not your problem. " - OH BOY WHAT DO I SEE... now i see what's wrong... https://pastebin.com/76jt7c01

Comment: " Unrelated to the issue at hand: "restraunt", in restraunt_locations should probably be spelled "restaurant", i.e. restaurant_locations " -My bad, my english really sucks...